# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property "Shield"

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, unity-game-engine

im about to start a Game Design & Development Study on the next few days, and i wanted to go ahead and take a step forward into Programming before i started to get the hang of it for the sake of time.

After a couple of days of creating a game project i got stuck on this silly situation where im Calling a Public Int "Shield" from Script 1 "PlayerDamageHandler" to Scrip 2 "PlayerHealthGUI", and at the beginning i could make a logic call from the Public Static Shield Int, but i need SHIELD to be a Public NOT static int, and i get that compiler warning whenever i remove "static" from the "Shield int"

I'm still taking my first steps into the universe of c# programming, understand my situation as an apprentice, and i need a Master to Assist me this time to clear my thoughts.

> (also i sleep 1/4 of the time i/m used to since i got obsessed with programming!)

Basicly, How would you call the "Shield" int from PlyDmghandler to PlyGUI making it so:

```
public int Shield = "a variable i want to change depending on which player i use it";
```

> making the int "shield" public (non static) and calling it from "PlyHealthGUI"

These are the first c# i made on my first days (my first code lines, they are really simple):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class PlayerDamageHandler : MonoBehaviour {

public bool explosion = false;
public GameObject exp;
public AudioClip expsound;
public float soundvalue = 1f;
public static int Shield = 15;

void OnTriggerEnter2D() {
Shield--;
}

void Update() {
        if (Shield <= 0)
die();
}
void die() {
    Destroy (gameObject);
}
}
```

And here is the 2*nd script that needs to call "Shield" to render its value on the User Interface "Text".

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerHealthGUI : MonoBehaviour {

Text text;

void Start () {
    text = GetComponent <Text>();
}

void Update () {
//The UserInterface Health/Shield used on the scene.
    text.text = ("-(") + PlayerDamageHandler.Shield + (")-");
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! There's an entire manual on the C# Programming Language. You should look at it before asking basic questions on the syntax of the language. See [C# Programming Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67ef8sbd.aspx) . For detailed reference, see the [C# Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/618ayhy6.aspx).

Comment: "Dog" is a class. "Spot" is an instance of the class "Dog".  An instance of a class is called an "object". You need something like: `Dog myDog = Spot;` so you can do `myDog.Fleas=myDog.Fleas+1;` Using `Dog.Fleas` makes no sense, as fleas are specific to a particular dog, not to dogs in general.

Comment: i will check it out, thx for the link Joch Saunders.

Comment: My  I ask, why do you want to make Shield non-static?

Comment: Because im making DIferent Player Objects with diferent "Shield" Values, and im still working on game balance so i ll be tweaking all the shield values all the time, and i need it to be non static in order to change its value from the editor without opening and closing the unity5 assembly editor every time i have to change their values.
Its for the sake of organization and i see the problem John just explained to me, but is there a way to call Shield to render it on the PlayerGUI without making Shield Static?

Comment: Im too drowsy right now and my eyes are all red for the leak of sleep
Im adding the links you shared with me to favorites @John Saunders, i will learn everything i can from them tomorrow, thanks you very much.

Comment: Yes. Keep Shield non-static, but then you need an **object reference** to a particular player in order to access it. Because it will be the "Shield" value of a specific player.

Comment: Oh, i get your point now John, wish i wasn`t drooling over my keyboard like a zombie to try it out right now, thx you for helping me!

Comment: After waking up this morning i did the script the way i needed it, thx u John for the link.
And it was a really really simple thing after all, i was way too drowsy to be honest, i found a simple solution, i just added:
`code
    Public Int BaseShield = "Introduce a Value";

    void Start (){
    Shield = BaseShield;
}
`
END...
(you can stone me now) xD